# Ansible config file 'ansible.cfg' is not accessible from the current directory

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.9.
We set it up using virtual environment so we do not have any ansible.cfg file.

So I am creating a ansible.cfg file in the current directory where my play book is kept.(to follow the precedence)

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable) 
ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
.ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

**Issue:** But when i run my playbook using my ADO pipeline the ansible.cfg is not being picked & shows message "No config file found; using defaults"

Note: I am importing playbook from another repository & Playbook is being executed for app deployment using azure devops ansible task.

Flow: Application code has playbook which imports playbook from repository called 'R1' from a directory called D1/common_play_book.yml
and parallel to this playbook i created ansible.cgf file in side the directory D1.

(I tried keeping ansible.cgf inside the directory of application code, parallel to the playbook which import a playbook from a another repository, but this also does not work)

am i missing something here ?
PS: Adding more structure details

```
Application Repository called "app_repo"
    1. azure-pipelines.yml --> Azure Devops Ansible task for devplyment use playbook defined at application side > app_platbook.yml (it imports centralized playbook playbook_from_lib.yml from other repo, all other apps are also using it)
    2. Structure 
    my_app (root)
        - app_playbook.yml
        - azure-pipelines.yml

Centralized playbook repository called: "playbook_lib"
    1. This is being imported at application side playbook (i.e in app_playbook.yml)
    2. Structure
    playbooks(root)
        - spring-app-playbooks
            - playbook_from_lib.yml
```

Next i tried with ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment variable which is like below at playbook level also, but did not work (export is required here but which path should i export here as my ansible.cfg is not in a static location)

```
---
- name: Deploying an application
  hosts: "{{ HOSTS }}"
  force_handlers: true
  gather_facts: false

  environment:
    ANSIBLE_CONFIG: "ansible.cfg"
```

For I am running my playbook from azure devops yml pipeline with the help of Ansible task

Comment: What is your parent-working-directory from where you run `ansible-playbook`? Just want to confirm, because I think it looks for ansible.cfg based on your pwd instead of where playbook is.

Comment: Are you actually running the playbook from the `D1` directory (i.e. `cd path/to/D1 && ansible-plabyook whatever.yml`) ? `ansible.cfg` has to be in the **current** directory as exactly mentioned in the piece of documentation you pasted above.

Comment: added more details for all these questions hope this help

Comment: Any thought / clue /suggestion please

Comment: @Rickkwa I provided information in the description. i tried keeping my ansible.cg parallel to both playbooks (app_playbook.yml & playbook_from_ilb.yml) but it does not work & gives same message "No config file found; using defaults" in my pipeline when playbook start executing.

Comment: Can you set that ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment variable as part of your pipeline before you run your playbook?

Comment: Yes i already tried (added in description) but did not work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with azure pipelines. Can you set it outside of the playbook? If using shell, something like `export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/absolute/path/to/ansible.cfg`?

Comment: not using shell before executing my playbook. Can i set 'ansible_config' env variable in playbook (i tried ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/path/to/ansible/cfg under "Environment" but does not work)

Comment: and another point is,  i am keeping this ansible.cfg in one of the git repository along with playbook

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure DevOps Pipeline starts from the work directory, the top-directory of the repo holding your pipeline. If your playbook and its ansible.cfg live in a subdirectory, for instance "other_repo", then you should set ANSIBLE_CONFIG like in this example:

```yaml
---
steps:
- task: Ansible@0
  displayName: 'Run Ansible playbook'
  env:
    ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE: ./echo_vault_env_var.sh
    ANSIBLE_CONFIG: other_repo/ansible/ansible.cfg
    ansibleVaultPass: '$(ansibleVaultPass)'
  inputs:
    ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
    playbookPathOnAgentMachine: 'other_repo/ansible/playbook.yml'
    inventoriesAgentMachine: 'file'
    inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: "$(inventoryFileOnAgentMachine)"
    sudoEnabled: true
    sudoUser: 'root'
    args: |
      -vv
    failOnStdErr: false
```